# Hibernate merge issue with one to one mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have a class hierarchy mapped with InheritanceType.JOINED in Hibernate (3.5.6 final) with JPA 2.0 -

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A{
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id",  nullable = false)
    private Foo foo;
    ...
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
public class B{
        ...
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "C_ID")
public class C{
        ...
}
```

And the `Foo` entity is  -

```
@Entity
public class Foo{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "foo")
    private A a

    // getters / setters omitted    
}
```

Now I saved the entity `Foo` with reference of `B` to field 'a'. Later on I would like to update the instance of Foo with reference of class `C` to property 'a', so what I did is -

```
loadedFooInstance.setA(new C());
entityManager.merge(loadedFooInstance);
```

But what I notice is - it doesn't delete the original B object which was assigned to that Foo object before assigning C. Because of this I need to delete all the reference of A assigned to that Foo instance **manually** before assigning new one. 
But I believe hibernate must have the way to deal with such scenarios and I'm missing something in my mapping.
Is anything wrong in my mapping.. or is this kind of mapping can be achieved in better way , so I don't need to deal with such manual work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OneToOne Relation ship is managed by the A-side not by the Foo-side. So you need to change relationship on the A-side (because hibernate payes ony attention to the side where the relationship is managed)

```
A old = loadedFooInstance.getA();
oldA.setFoo(null);
C c = new C();
c.setFoo(loadedFooInstance);
/*and it is good practic to update foo too*/
loadedFooInstance.setA(c);
```

The other way is to change the side which manage the relationship:

```
public abstract class A{
   ...
   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a") 
   private Foo foo;
   ...
}

public class Foo{
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id",  nullable = false)
    private A a
    ...
 }
```

But this would change your database layout too!

Comment: I don't want to change the DB layout.. because I want to apply delete cascade.. so If Foo gets deleted then A must be deleted automatically. In the second option its not possible to apply such delete cascade, right?

Comment: @Premraj M: For the second scenario: you could apply a cascade = CascadeType.ALL on to Foo.a.  - I don't know if it works, on the mappedBy side

Comment: But I don't want to keep Id of A in Foo, so If Foo gets deleted by HQL then A should be automatically deleted (With delete cascade at DB end).. does this makes sense now to have this mapping ?

Comment: @Premraj M: Summary: every hibernate relationship has two sides: the side which is maintaining the relationship and the side which is "readonly", every relationship has also a side where the foraign key is stored and the other side (mapped by). Normaly the relationship maintaining side and the key storing side is the same. -- You can make the not Storing side, the maintainig side  by setting the "inverse" Flag and set the storing side to read only (update=false, insert=false). -- But I don't know the cascade delete works from the "mapped by" side to the "foraign key" side.

Comment: @Premraj M: But from my experience, changing the maintaining side, often causes problems, so don't do this as along as you not really need it. And write a bunch of test cases for this relation ship! -- If you have more question, then ask a new question, because all this is out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right here in this schema. When you delete B you want to delete Foo, hence A is the owning side of the relationship. So without the existence of B, Foo should not exist. But what you are doing now is removing B from Foo, hence violating the relationship as now there is no B. You should follow Ralph's advice#2. Advice#1 will work fine, but clearly Foo should be the owning side. And the cascading will work from the mapped by side also. Your defined relationship is not correct.

**EDIT :**

In order to set the existing B in Foo to C:
This is almost similar to Ralph's ealier Advice#1

```
Foo foo = entityManager.find(Foo.class, id);
B b = foo.getA();
entityManager.remove(b); //Explicitly remove or B still remains in database as B is the owning side
C c = new C();
c.setFoo(foo);
entityManager.persist(c);  //c is the owning side, hence save c and not foo
entityManager.refresh(foo);
```

Comment: Nope.. When I delete Foo, I want to delete B or C whatever related to Foo.. Does this make sense now? or can you provide the sample to define relationship with this requirement.

Comment: @Premraj M - You should then explicitly remove all associated instances of A from foo, and then set foo in the new A instance and persist. This is required as you cannot apply cascade all on Foo from the A side, otherwise, the removal of A will remove Foo too. See edit.

Comment: @Premraj M - the older A instace i.e. B is never removed from the database, i think it should not exist in there. Also C has to be saved or a cascading merge operation performed on foo.